# why is my iis express faster than my iis 7.5?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, iis-express

I tried to look up if there is any similar question but in vain.

I executed a query with ajax and called my iis express server (under visual studio 2015) and i got the response in **260ms**:

[image]

But when I deployed my website on my iis 7.5 (on the same machine as my iis express) and I executed the **same query**, I got the response in **1.52s**:
[image]

This is the case for all my queries, normally it should faster because there is no debugging after deployment,  what can possibly be the problem ? why my iis express is faster than my iis7.5 ?

Comment: Run a profiler please.

Comment: What is url that you use to access website on IIS 7.5? Are you using localhost or hostname in url?

Comment: because when your hitting a deployed web server there is probably some added time for authentication/security/firewall. Different places in your web traffic will stop and inspect a request before passing that line of defense that iis express does not worry about that. Only a guess but no way to know for sure without a profiler.